# How to place a new MenuItem after Help>Welcome in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to place a menu next to Help>Welcome>Abhishek Menu.
I tried different approaches but couldn't get the desired result.
Please suggest me some way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use menu contributions and the locationURI should be: menu:help?after=intro